# Java - Passing a char variable to a method and returning a boolean?

Tags: java

Hello I am very new to Java, I wanted to know if it were possible to pass a character to a method, and then return true if this character is valid.

I have this method:

```
public void btnColor(char c) {
    if (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
        // Change button color
    }
}
```

What I would like is to have something like this, although it won't let me do this:

```
public boolean btnColor(char c, boolean b) {
    if (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So it takes a character variable `c` and returns true if valid. Is there a best practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: you need to provide a return false after closing the if block. for all possible flows, the method needs to return a boolean

Comment: `return hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c));`

Comment: @Stultuske: nope. one line is all he needs

Comment: You don't need an extra `boolean` parameter either, changing the return type was all the modification you needed for the signature

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, it can be done in one line, but my point was he was missing a return statement for certain flows

Comment: Your question suggests that you would benefit from going through some intro to Java textbooks and tutorials as these are very basic concepts.

Comment: if a valid character means it is 0-9 and a-z then use Character class's isLetter and isDigitMethod().

Comment: Thank you @Stultuske your answer was correct I needed to provide both `return true` and `return false`.

Comment: @jb2002 my answer was just one possibility: the comment from Hovercraft Full of Eels shows how to do the same in just one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in order to always return some value. This should be possible and acceptable with Java.

```
public boolean btnColor(char c, boolean b) {
    if (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
        return true; // this will return in case of your condition is true
    }
    return false; // this will return otherwise.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this single line

```
public boolean btnColor(char c, boolean b) {
   return hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

It'll return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

All code paths need to return a value.

```
public boolean btnColor(char c, boolean b) {
    if (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
        // add additional code
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not very proper : if computation is true return true, if not return false ==> return computation is easier

Comment: @azro if you want to add some additional code in the if statement block, it will be necessary to add an if statement ...

Answer (score 0):

When you have `public` **boolean** `methodName`, it means it MUST return a **boolean**. Having an "IF" statement in your code, means it can split up to a two possible ways: IF-true and IF-false. You have declared the true statement:

```
 if (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
        return true;
```

So you are covering 1/2 of the solution. But what if it is false ? Nothing ? This is why you have problems, so to solve your problem you code should looks like this:

```
public boolean btnColor(char c) {
        if (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
    }
```

Now if it is containing the character - it returns TRUE, but if it is not containing it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use conditionals in a single line:

```
public boolean btnColor(char c) {
    return (hm.getHiddenWordUpdated().contains(String.valueOf(c))) ? true:false;
}
```